# Why does MySQL pack the date type in its internal representation

Tags: mysql, binary

While researching this answer [How datetime values are stored in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937211/how-datetime-values-are-stored-in-mysql), at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html I came upon the following statement:

> DATETIME: Eight bytes: A four-byte integer for date packed as
>   YYYY×10000 + MM×100 + DD and a four-byte integer for time packed as
>   HH×10000 + MM×100 + SS

What is the reason for packing a date value this way [instead of all the subcomponents seperately? Is it just to save space or does it somehow help with datetime calculations?

Comment: In theory, it should be much faster/trivial to compare dates stored that way. If you stored year month and day separately then in order to compare two dates for greater and less than, you need to check whose year is larger, if they are same then check whose month is larger, then day, then hour, minute, second and so forth.

Comment: @SalmanA This sounds like an answer, not a comment.